# Understanding question involving topology generated by subset

Tags: general-topology

I have only had one lecture in topology so far this semester. In that lecture we covered what a topology on a set is, and that's pretty much it. We haven't even discussed topological bases. My lecturer has given us homework questions, one of which I don't understand. Word for word the question is

"Let $E$ be a set and $S\subseteq E$. Show that the topology $(T_S)$ on $E$ generated by $S$ consists of the set $E$ together with all subsets which are families of intersections of finite families of sets in $S$."

My problem is twofold. Firstly I am not aware of how a subset generates a topology on the parent set, and Google searching has not been able to furnish me with such a definition. If anyone can give me the definition of a topology generated by a subset I'd be halfway there. The other stumbling block is that I don't actually fully understand what the 2nd part of the question is asking. What exactly are "all subsets which are families of intersections of finite families of sets in $S$"? I'd much appreciate someone explaining in clear mathematical English what exactly the question is asking.

Normally I'd just ask the lecturer what he means, but it's the weekend and he wants us to present this set of questions on Monday, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo?

Comment: It doesn't make sense in the current form; isn't $T_S$ defined somewhere before? Are you sure it shouldn't be $S\subseteq 2^E$? Then it could be the smallest topology containing $S$ and the sentence could be "...which are *unions* of intersections of finite families..." but that's just guessing.

Comment: @PeterFranek Unfortunately I was just given a printed list of questions and what I wrote out is the question word for word. The sheet has no extra information about $T_s$. Thanks for the help though I'll answer the question as you have put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is a typo and that $S \subseteq 2^E$ (since otherwise it really does not make sense to me): the topology generated by $S$ is by definition the smallest topology $\Gamma$ on $E$ such that $S \subseteq \Gamma$, and what you have to do is to show that the open sets of $\Gamma$ are exactly all the unions (possibly infinite) of all the finite intersections of sets coming from $S$.

Hint: show that all such sets must belong to any topology containing $S$, and then show that they suffice to define a topology (so that it really has to be the smallest one).

Comment: Thank you, the question posed by you is definitely something I can now answer. If the learned people on MSE agree that the question makes no sense I'm sure my lecturer made a typo and will have to accept an answer to your improved question.

Comment: I wouldn't put myself among the learned people of MSE ;) but still, I do think that the question makes more sense in this form. Maybe your lecturer really meant something else, but this I cannot know and it would have been his fault not to have expressed it clearly.